# Create asp.net page so I can create simple T-SQL queries

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET site using a SQL Server database. I have to run a lot of small queries to do sums, counts, etc on the fly. I am doing them direct in SQL but I am not always on the LAN to do so.

Is there a simple way to create an ASP.NET site so that I can run these basic queries direct from my site?

Comment: in all cases you have to be connected to sql server. if you are using the website from the internet, then you need to host your website and db some where on the cloud or on a hosting server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool, https://rickbergfalk.github.io/sqlpad/ for this purpose.
This is a web-based tool to run SQL server queries. Download and deploy it. It will help you